# Semaphore with multiple hosts/dockers

Tags: javascript, node.js

My app receives process messages (currently from RabbitMQ). For some messages only one message can be proccessed at once, some other messages don't need any concurrency. The prefetch is configured for 5 messages .

For that, I use the package Semaphore (https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore) and it works fine on one server. In the app, messages, which need concurrency, wait that other ones finished then it starts, and the app continue to receive messages and process them during the waiting time.

But now, I would to deploy my app to multiple servers or docker, and the package Semaphore doesn't manage multiple hosts.
I tryed the package singleton-process (https://www.npmjs.com/package/singleton-process) but it doesn't wait when the semaphore is acquired by an other process.

Do you have any idea of a package to use for that or how to process my messages differently?